# attribute Required If (Ranged If) setup not giving me the forms text box as error, but does throw error

Tags: c#, webforms, attributes, blazor, required

I have a custom Required if that works fine. I then needed a Ranged If - Required if another item was a certain value, and it needs to be within a range. this does work - but does not throw the error under the box. I assume due to "return new ValidationResult". is there a way to just throw error in custom attributes that I'm missing that will link back to the text box?

Ranged if reads like this: Value I want to look at, the value I want to make it require, min and max values for the range.

```
public string IsMonetized { get; set; } 

// [RequiredIf("IsMonetized", "Yes", "Please Enter a Value")]
// [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter an Amount greater than 0")]
[RangedIf("IsMonetized", "Yes", 1, 200)]
public double MaxAmount { get; set; }

//[Range(1, 200, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter an Amount greater than 0")]
[RangedIf("IsMonetized", "Yes", 1, 200)]
public double? AnnualAmount { get; set; }
```

```
public class RangedIfAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    private String PropertyName { get; set; }
    private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }
    private double max { get; set; }
    private double min { get; set; }

    public RangedIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue, double Min, double Max)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
        min = Min;
        max = Max;
    }

    public RangedIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue, double Min, double Max, String Errormessage)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
        ErrorMessage = Errormessage;
        min = Min;
        max = Max;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
        Type type = instance.GetType();
        Object proprtyvalue = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);

        try
        {
            if (proprtyvalue == null)
            {
                if (DesiredValue == null)
                {
                    if (min <= (double)value && (double)value <= max)
                    {
                        return base.IsValid(value, context); // Null was intended , and value in range - Valid
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (proprtyvalue.ToString().Equals(DesiredValue))
            {
                if (min <= (double)value && (double)value <= max)
                {
                    return base.IsValid(value, context); // desired = property value, and value in range - Valid
                }
            }

            // This should submit Not Valid
            return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(context.DisplayName));
        }
        catch
        {
            // this should submit not valid - the required item is null
            return new ValidationResult($"Value must be within the range of {min} and {max}");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried looking through all of the custom attributes information I can find and it seems nothing is coming up useful. the Validate.Success can send a successful validation, but it seems there is no Auto Failure (Validate.Failure). seems like an over site to the attribute system.

The boxes on both do nothing right away - and are not flagged - but a validation summary at the bottom will read:

The MaxAmount field is required. - Max Amount Field falls to the bottom with not matching the correct if logic.

Value must be within the range of 1 and 200 - annual amount will hit the try/catch since it was null and throws an error.

Again - it stops the form from submitting, but there is no indication what box (normally highlights red when validation fails) fails to validate.

Comment: This may not be what you want to hear, but I highly recommend moving away from attribute validation to fluent validation. You have so much more control over validation and you can add custom messages based on different invalid conditions - it's super nice. There is also a [Blazor-specific NuGet package](https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation) for easily implementing fluent validation on your `EditForm`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "fix" was this line for a false return:

```html
                return new ValidationResult($"Value must be within the range of {min} and {max}", new[] { context.MemberName });
```

Basically this allows the system to link back which entry box needed to be flagged, while you are able to send a custom message for each failed area. my bottom one could read "no null values" but having them say between A and B sounds better.

Here is the finished product:

```html
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select an Option")]
        public string IsMonetized { get; set; }

        [RangedIf("IsMonetized", "Yes", 1, 200)]
        public double? AnnualAmount { get; set; }
```

```html
public class RangedIfAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    private String PropertyName { get; set; }
    private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }
    private double max { get; set; }
    private double min { get; set; }

    public RangedIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue, double Min, double Max)
    {

        PropertyName = propertyName;
        DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
        min = Min;
        max = Max;
    }

    public RangedIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue, double Min, double Max, String Errormessage)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
        ErrorMessage = Errormessage;
        min = Min;
        max = Max;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
        Type type = instance.GetType();
        Object proprtyvalue = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);
        try
        {
            if (proprtyvalue == null)
            {
                if (DesiredValue == null)
                {
                    if (min <= (double)value && (double)value <= max)
                    {
                        return base.IsValid(value, context); // Null was intended , and value in range
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new ValidationResult($"Value must be within the range of {min} and {max}", new[] { context.MemberName }); // null was intended but value not in range
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success; //property value is null - needs to be selected first - do not trigger
                }
            }
            else if (proprtyvalue.ToString().Equals(DesiredValue))
            {
                if (min <= (double)value && (double)value <= max)
                {
                    return base.IsValid(value, context); // property = intended value and value in range
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ValidationResult($"Value must be within the range of {min} and {max}", new[] { context.MemberName }); //property = inteded value but not in range
                }
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success; //not required
        }
        catch
        {
            // most likely a null value
            return new ValidationResult($"Value must be within the range of {min} and {max}", new[] { context.MemberName });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute needs to be inherited from ValidationAttribute. This contains a property called ErrorMessage which can be set within the constructor.

Here is an example of an attribute which validates if a date is always in the future.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public sealed class FromBeforeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public FromBeforeAttribute()
        {
            ErrorMessage = "The date cannot be in the past";
        }


        public override bool IsValid(object? value)
        {
            if (value is null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var result = DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out DateTime newValue);
            return result && newValue != default && DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, newValue) > 0;
        }
    }
```